# cassandra 2 complaining about Java 7 when I have Java 7 installed

Tags: java, cassandra

```
$ cassandra 
Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

OK, what's going on in that part of the init script?

```
java_ver_output=`"${JAVA:-java}" -version 2>&1`

jvmver=`echo "$java_ver_output" | awk -F'"' 'NR==1 {print $2}'`
JVM_VERSION=${jvmver%_*}
JVM_PATCH_VERSION=${jvmver#*_}


if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.7" ] ; then
    echo "Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later."
    exit 1;
fi
```

Hmm, if I get the version at the command line:

```
$ java_ver_output=`"${JAVA:-java}" -version 2>&1`

$ echo $java_ver_output
java version "1.7.0_55" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

$ JVM_VERSION=${jvmver%_*}

$ echo $JVM_VERSION
1.7.0
```

If I run `which java`:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

If I put that line in the script:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

The frustrating part here is that I've got this running in the past but since I bounced the server I can't get cassandra to start.

So I'm confused here, how is Cassandra confused about what version of Java I'm running? How do I get cassandra running? Is `1.7.0_55` not Java 7 (I don't get Java's naming convention)?

Comment: Modify the script to print out `$JVM_VERSION` so you can see what it is actually getting.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen good suggestion, I got 1.6.0 but I don't get that when I run those commands at the command line. WTF.

Comment: Try running `which java` both outside and inside the script to see which executables are being referred to.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I updated the question. I can't see a difference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "print it in full"? You must be joking.

Comment: @jcollum I'm somewhat newb in -nix, but isn't usr a user-specific directory? Is the script run by the same user as your bash tests? Sorry if I'm wrong - I haven't seen a -nix machine for quite some time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/conf/cassandra-env.sh

Comment: @Ordous you're thinking of /home/[username]; unix directory structure is definitely confusing

Comment: What OS are you doing this on? The `[ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.7" ]` seems to rely on a non-standard `test` feature, namely `\<` giving you ascii ordering. For me this works on ubuntu because /bin/sh is `dash` and dash implements its own version of `test ([)`, but it doesn't work on Illumos because the Illumos `/bin/sh` just uses `/bin/test` which doesn't know about `\<`.

Comment: @jcollum have you installed the jre or jdk?

Comment: The `ll` for `which java` ultimately points to  `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java` -- so JDK I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra java reference issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119211/cassandra-java-reference-issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same error message when trying to start Cassandra. But I notised that I only got the error when starting Cassandra as root. It worked when I started Cassandra as my local user.

It turned out that java only was configured for my local user:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
$ sudo java -version
sudo: java: command not found
```

This fixed the problem:

Tell the system that you have JRE installed (update usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java to your current path):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java" 1
```

Set the new JRE as default:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java
```

Now java is installed for root and Cassandra can be started as root without the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if this actually worked -- it turned out that Cassandra was not going to work for my app so I ditched it a couple of days later. But it was a helpful answer, so it gets the answer mark.

Answer (score 7):

Per documentation: http://wiki.helioviewer.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra_Installation

> **Set JAVA_HOME**
>
> Make sure JAVA_HOME is set: echo $JAVA_HOME

So make sure `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `/path/to/jdk7`

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/conf/cassandra-env.sh -- I don't know why that would matter, the script doesn't use JAVA_HOME -- and those docs are 3 years old

Comment: @jcollum: I believe you are looking for `JAVA_HOME` in the wrong script (cassandra-env.sh), it is indeed used in the "cassandra startup script" (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/bin/cassandra). As experiment simply setup `JAVA_HOME` to the directory of your JDK (e.g.: mine on Mac OS is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home` and I have it as a environment variable) and see if cassandra starts correctly. I am using a version 1.2.X so cannot test that at the moment. HTH.

Comment: if you look at the script if it doesn't find JAVA_HOME it will default to just "java" bit it's still not working

Comment: are you sure the `java` command in your path is from the JDK7, or is it another version? Just to be sure I would specify `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the JDK7 directory... you can also check which version you are using (in case you have multiple versions installed) using: `update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem I changed $JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path I found it from:

```
System Preferences -> Java -> java (tab in Java Control Panel) -> View -> Path
```

I had two version of java and the default one was the old version of java.

Answer (score 1):

See this [CASSANDRA-11716](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11716) issue. The solution posted there worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me.I was trying to run cassandra with supervisor and was getting java error.So I figured out that I had to just set java path in cassandra.in.sh. I just had to set JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_171 and save it and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue when installing DSE 4.6 on Linux. Issue is resolved when you set JAVA_HOME (as root) to the directory where JRE 1.7.x installed.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a newer issue now that Java 7 update 101 has been released.  I installed this version which broke Cassandra:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.101-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64
```

Installing a previous version (update 99) fixed the issue:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.99-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64
```

I'm guessing somewhere in the cassandra startup script a Regex is written for 2 characters in the update version, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in Cassandra: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11661