# Error to install cassandra

Tags: cassandra, debian, apt-get

I had installed the version 1.1 of Cassandra, but after I discovered that the last version of Cassandra is 2.1 and I updated my source list, but I am having error to install Cassandra using apt-get:

```
Setting up cassandra (2.1.0~rc3) ...
vm.max_map_count = 1048575
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
invoke-rc.d: initscript cassandra, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing cassandra (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cassandra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and now I cant use Cassandra anymore, so, how can I solve this?

`java -version`:

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

And,

```
dpkg -l | grep jre

ii  default-jre                           1:1.6-47                           amd64        Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
ii  default-jre-headless                  1:1.6-47                           amd64        Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)
ii  icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64             6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1               amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
ii  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64             6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1               amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
ii  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64             7u65-2.5.1-2~deb7u1                amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
ii  openjdk-6-jre:amd64                   6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1               amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64          6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1               amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                     6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1               all          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:amd64                   7u65-2.5.1-2~deb7u1                amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64          7u65-2.5.1-2~deb7u1                amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-7-jre-lib                     7u65-2.5.1-2~deb7u1                all          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output of `java -version`?

Comment: Any chance this question/answer(s) fixes your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190063/cassandra-2-complaining-about-java-7-when-i-have-java-7-installed

Comment: java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

If this was a fresh install and you have no data, try purging the installed cassandra package, first, then just install again:

```
apt-get remove --purge cassandra
apt-get install cassandra
```

You will need to re-edit any changes you made to /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml as purging a package removes everything, including configurations.  During the remove, you might also get a warning that /var/lib/cassandra/data won't be removed because of existing data - after purging, recursively remove /var/lib/cassandra, so that you are really starting over fresh, then re-install.

Comment: I tried that, but the error keeps, in fact, anything that I try to install I get this error.

Comment: Can we see what `dpkg -l | grep jre` returns?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicions were tipped-off by this line:

```
Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

And your response in the comments confirms it:

```
java version "1.6.0_32" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-1~deb7u1) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

You will need to install a JRE of version 1.7 or greater.  Also, DataStax does not recommend running the OpenJDK with Cassandra.  Download and install version 7 (or later) of Oracle's JRE/JDK.  Here is a link to DataStax's documentation on [installing the Oracle JRE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installJREJNAabout_c.html).

Comment: This advice is of little use. All commands for installing Java version 7 fail because it is complaining about the broken cassandra installation.

Comment: Actually, I lied. Every link other than yours used apt-get to install java. Your link however doesn't. Thus, it worked :). Thanks for finding that link.

Answer (score 0):

May be below details will help you.Recommended Version.
For Apache Cassandra 2.0.x and 2.1.x, the latest version of the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) 7 or 8 is required. The JDK is recommended.

For Apache Cassandra 2.2.x, 3.0.x, and 3.x, the latest version of the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) 8 is required. The JDK is recommended.